# Use a comma-separated string in an `IN ()` in MySQL

Tags: sql, mysql

If a user-defined variable `@x` is a string of comma separated numbers, e.g. `'1,2,4'`, is there a way to use it in an `IN ()` function?

Specifically:

```
SET @x := '1,2,4';
SELECT * FROM t WHERE c IN (@x);
```

does not select rows in t where c equals 1 or 2 or 4.

Comment: are you sure? seemed like everything ok in this code

Comment: @Vadyus - Yes, really.  See below.

Comment: Check this ::

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10480568/comma-separated-values-in-mysql-in-clause

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't do this directly using a variable.  Based on what you have now, the server is trying to execute `select * form t where c in ('1,2,3');` ... which clearly isn't what you want given that you're checking to see if c contains the single string given.

You must generate dynamic SQL based off of your list in order to get this to work.

Comment: Fair enough. I'll put the values in a wee temp table and join.

Answer (score 1):

> Maybe there is no point of answering this question now, but recently I faced same problem and this is how I resolved it.
>
> It worked for me, hope this is what you were looking for.

```
select * from table_name where CONCAT(',',('1,2,4'),',') LIKE CONCAT('%,',column_name,',%');
```

> **Example:** *It will look like this*

```
select * from t where ',1,2,4,' LIKE '%,2,%';
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
SET @x := '1,2,4';
SET @sql = CONCAT('SELECT * FROM t WHERE c IN (', @x, ');');

PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
EXECUTE stmt;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
```