# how to show data when a cell contains more multivalue separated by commas

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have following code but i have a problem.

```
$query = "SELECT p.*,(TO_DAYS(p.start_date) - TO_DAYS(NOW())) AS daydiff FROM #__jblance_project p ".
                 "WHERE p.status=".$db->quote('COM_JBLANCE_OPEN')." AND p.approved=1  AND '$now' > p.start_date AND  p.id_category=202 ".
                 "ORDER BY p.is_featured DESC, p.id DESC ".
```

the problem is when the field id_category has more than just one value like

```
202,203,204
```

it is not showing any result althout i have changes the code to

```
AND  p.id_category=202 OR .id_category=203 OR .id_category=204
```

as the cell contains all values separated by comma

any advice.

Thanks
D.

Comment: sorry ia am new to this web what u mean

Comment: thats ok. save ur self from nt getting downvote

Comment: @user1859876 Parado did it for you, you can edit your question now to see how he changed it.

Comment: I suggest to normalize your database.

Comment: You should consider changing your database to contain only one entry there, instead of a list of comma separated values.  But you might check out the [`FIND_IN_SET`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_find-in-set) syntax.

Answer (score 0):

```
$query = "SELECT p.*,(TO_DAYS(p.start_date) - TO_DAYS(NOW())) AS daydiff FROM #__jblance_project as p ". "WHERE p.status=".$db->quote('COM_JBLANCE_OPEN')." AND p.approved=1 AND '$now' > p.start_date AND p.id_category=202 ". "ORDER BY p.is_featured DESC, p.id DESC ".
```

add as FROM #__jblance_project as p

Comment: Hi I have already edited the code with the p. but still no result i can see. I only see result when t cell has one value for example 202 but not when a cell has two values 202,203

Answer (score 0):

Expanding on my comment, consider changing this:

```
SELECT p.*,(TO_DAYS(p.start_date) - TO_DAYS(NOW())) AS daydiff 
FROM #__jblance_project p
WHERE p.status=<something>
AND p.approved=1  AND '$now' > p.start_date 
AND p.id_category=202
ORDER BY p.is_featured DESC, p.id DESC
```

To something like:

```
SELECT p.*,(TO_DAYS(p.start_date) - TO_DAYS(NOW())) AS daydiff 
FROM #__jblance_project p
WHERE p.status=<something>
AND p.approved=1  AND '$now' > p.start_date 
AND 0 < FIND_IN_SET(202, p.id_category)
ORDER BY p.is_featured DESC, p.id DESC
```

Also, I'd probably write the full PHP statement as:

```
$query = sprintf('SELECT p.*,(TO_DAYS(p.start_date) - TO_DAYS(NOW())) AS daydiff 
    FROM #__jblance_project p
    WHERE p.status=%s
    AND p.approved=1  AND '%s' > p.start_date 
    AND 0 < FIND_IN_SET(202, p.id_category)
    ORDER BY p.is_featured DESC, p.id DESC', $db->quote('COM_JBLANCE_OPEN'), $now);
```

Note that this is more of a workaround than the "correct" solution.  You should really consider reformatting your database such that you have one entry per field, as opposed to a comma separated list.

The second two use the [`FIND_IN_SET`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_find-in-set) string function which should awkwardly accomplish your goal.

[This related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10480568/comma-separated-values-in-mysql-in-clause) and especially the answers and comments may be instructive.

Answer (score 0):

There is no really solid way to do this... You're stuck with something ugly like:

```
id_category LIKE "%,123" OR
id_category LIKE "123,%" OR
id_category LIKE "%,123,%" OR
id_category = "123"
```

The reason this is so ugly, is because it's a bad idea to use delimited fields like this. Instead you should create a separate table with two columns:

- An id for projects
- An id for categories

This is a many-to-many relationship.

If you do want to go further with your hack, I would suggest to not format the id_category like :

```
123,456,789
```

But instead:

```
,123,456,789,
```

So include a comma before and after. At the very least you can simplify your like query to:

```
id_category LIKE "%,123,%"
```

**Edit:** I did not know about `FIND_IN_SET`. This sounds like a valid solution, although normalizing your data will still give you a much better outcome.

Answer (score 0):

You have use IN() keyword in mysql.

```
p.id_category IN (202,203,204)
```

Here you can pass the dynamic category id array like this.

```
$array_cat_id = impload(',' ,$pass_array_of_the_id);

p.id_category IN ($array_cat_id)
```