# How to write query for comparing column having comma-separated values?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, joomla2.5

I am Using Joomla 2.5. I am using MYSQL database. 
I have a table `job_field` with the following columns:

```
cat_id  |  location_id
-----------------------
 1,4    |   66,70
```

I need to compare it with another table `job_value`

```
cat_id  |  location_id | name
--------------------------------
 1      |   70         | Atul
 4      |   70,80      | Amit
 4      |   80,66      | Amol
 1      |   66         | Pritam    
 3      |   70         | Rahul
 2      |   66,90      | Ajit
 1      |   74         | Raju
 4      |   65,22      | Manoj
```

I want output to compare `cat_id` and `location_id` columns from first table `job_details` with second table `job_value` columns `cat_id` and `location_id`.

And it will check each value from 1st table (`job_details`) that is `location_id` column value (66, 70) separately with 2nd table (`job_value`) `location_id` column. I will get output array as

```
  Array (
    1 70     Atul
    4 70,80  Amit
    4 80,66  Amol
    1 66     Pritam
 )
```

Comment: What RDBMS are you using?

Comment: This is not a normalized structure. Basically: you're doomed - unless you reconsider the structure.

Comment: in a specific sql language dialect? is it only one or two values separate by a comma?

Comment: [Is storing a delimited list in a database column really that bad?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3653574)

Comment: It stores multiple values for location_id in table so its complicated

Comment: I've read this question 5 times now and I still have no idea what joins with what and what you would like to be returned

Comment: please change your structure to be optimized

Comment: It doesn't count in _which CMS_ you use a badly designed DB schema... So specifying Joomla 2.5 is completely irrelevant...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this ::

```
SELECT 
* 
FROM table1
JOIN table2  ON FIND_IN_SET(table1.location_id, table2.location_id) > 0
```

You can also refer 
[Comma separated values in MySQL "IN" clause](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10480568/comma-separated-values-in-mysql-in-clause)

Comment: this return empty result set

Answer (score 3):

This is a **<sub>bad</sub>bad<sup>bad</sup>** structure. Even if the problem can be solved, it shouldn't be solved. It will be slow, and unmaintainable.

Instead of the poor structure, something along these lines should be created for this part of the DB:

```
CREATE TABLE PERSON (
    person_id BIGINT,
    name VARCHAR(64),
    PRIMARY KEY (person_id)
);

CREATE TABLE LOCATION (
    location_id BIGINT,
    name VARCHAR(64),
    PRIMARY KEY (location_id)
);
CREATE TABLE CAT (
    cat_id BIGINT,
    name VARCHAR(64),
    PRIMARY KEY (cat_id)
);

CREATE TABLE CAT_LOCATION (
    cat_id BIGINT,
    location_id BIGINT,
    PRIMARY KEY (cat_id,location_id),
    FOREIGN KEY (cat_id) REFERENCES cat(cat_id),
    FOREIGN KEY (location_id) REFERENCES location(location_id)
);

CREATE TABLE CAT_LOCATION_PERSON (
    cat_id BIGINT,
    location_id BIGINT,
    person_id BIGINT,
    PRIMARY KEY (cat_id,location_id,person_id),
    FOREIGN KEY (cat_id) REFERENCES cat(cat_id),
    FOREIGN KEY (location_id) REFERENCES location(location_id),
    FOREIGN KEY (person_id) REFERENCES person(person_id)
);
```

And then it is easier than easy to get what you want by doing simple joins:

```
SELECT cl.cat_id, cl.location_id, p.name
FROM CAT_LOCATION cl 
JOIN CAT_LOCATION_PERSON clp on cl.cat_id = clp.cat_id and cl.location_id=clp.location_id
JOIN PERSON p on clp.person_id = p.person_id
```

(I *refuse* to write a query that would provide the output in the specified format, with numeric values separated by comma... (though it is possible through MySQL's GROUP_CONCAT functionality easily))