# Use LIKE with CONCAT

Tags: mysql, sql

Can I use like with `CONCAT`? I cannot find anywhere that says otherwise. I'm trying the following and gives an error:

```
SELECT *, (select count(*) from acts where bookingType like '%CONCAT(bookingTypes_id, ',')%') as how_many FROM bookingTypes order by bookingType
```

NOTE: I am using `CONCAT` with comma because the `bookingType` field is basically a list of numbers comma separated e.g. 40,14,45 - and I can't just search for e.g. 4 as it would show when shouldn't  - is there a better way to search within that field?

Comment: LIKE isn't designed to work like IN

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is usually better not to store comma separated values in a field, but you can use CONCAT this way:

```
SELECT
  *,
  (SELECT COUNT(*)
   FROM   acts
   WHERE  CONCAT(',', bookingType, ',')
          LIKE CONCAT('%,', bookingTypes_id, ',%')) AS how_many
FROM bookingTypes
ORDER BY bookingType
```

or you can use FIND_IN_SET:

```
SELECT
  *,
  (SELECT COUNT(*)
   FROM   acts
   WHERE  FIND_IN_SET(bookingTypes_id, bookingType)>0) AS how_many
FROM bookingTypes
ORDER BY bookingType
```

Comment: first option perfect, many thanks... slight error in code should be: ...LIKE CONCAT('%'... remove comma after %

Comment: @DarrenSweeney i fixed the first query, if I unterstand correctly it's better to use a concat also on bookingType, so the where clause will be `',40,14,45,' LIKE '%,4,%'` and it will match bookingTypes_id even if it's at the beginning or at the end of the string

Comment: Yeah I agree but I'm finding flaws in this whole process I think, and wondering whether I should just have a separate table for act:bookingType relationship each on it's own line - when I add using implode the first and last don't have preceding or trailing commas which makes this query fall down

Comment: @DarrenSweeney yes queries like this can't be optimized and can't make use of an index, please see also this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10480568/comma-separated-values-in-mysql-in-clause it is usually better to insert each relationship on it's own line

Answer (score 2):

Try this :-

```
SELECT *
FROM acts
WHERE bookingTypes LIKE CONCAT('%', 
(SELECT bookingTypes FROM bookingTypes order by bookingType LIMIT 1), '%');
```