# MySQL Query with IN return empty

Tags: php, mysql

I had an issue of while run a query with IN key return empty. Here's my query:

```
 SELECT * FROM `sc_miscellaneous` where discount_for=4 AND stud_id IN (1,2) AND status=1
```

This query returns a correct results. But if i use `IN (2,3)` or `IN (2)` means zero results. Eg.

```
SELECT * FROM `sc_miscellaneous` where discount_for=4 AND stud_id IN (2,3) AND status=1
```

Table **sc_miscellaneous**:

```
ID Miscellaneous misc_amount discount discount_for class stud_id               status
1  5                200        2        4            1    1,2,3,4,5,6,            1  
                                                          7,8,9,10,11, 
                                                          12,13,14,15,16,
                                                          17,18,19 

2  6                500        2        4            1    1,2,3,4,5,6,7           1
```

Advance Thanks.

Comment: What is the type of stud_id?

Comment: refer [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10480568/comma-separated-values-in-mysql-in-clause) or [this](http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/52492/mysql-using-comma-separated-values)

Answer (score 1):

**Updated**

Use following query

```
SELECT * FROM `sc_miscellaneous` 
WHERE stud_id LIKE '%,2,%' OR  stud_id LIKE '%,3,%' 
  OR  stud_id LIKE '2,%,' OR  stud_id LIKE '3,%'
  OR  stud_id LIKE '%,2' OR  stud_id LIKE '%,3'
```

As you are having varchar comma separated list.

Check

1)if that UNIQUE number is in between comma separated list,

2)OR if is that at the start

3)OR if its at the end.

Comment: This will also recover, for example, stud_id = 12 or stud_id = 35. If you're going comma seperated (which you shouldn't) then the comma's need to be included in the LIKE ( '%,2,%' ) and you need to add a comma at the start and end of the value in the column.

Comment: but if we use LIKE means, column have '22,32' means its also selected. but we need exact result. -thanks

Comment: Thanks Friends, i got it. @Erik and jQuery PHP

Answer (score 0):

I think your stud_id type was int make it to varchar and run the code

```
stud_id(int)---->change to varchar
```

you have to work with

```
in_array()
```

Comment: type of the stud_id is varchar only.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think the way you are writing your query using `IN` clause is the right way.

Please follow this [link](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/mysql/mysql-in-clause.htm)

According to the documentation, if `stud_id` is an integer then you can check it with multiple integers using `IN Clause`. Like if stud_id = 1, then you can write `stud_id` IN ( 1,2,3).

For your requirement you may have to write multiple queries for extracting data and compare.

Comment: if change the type of stud_id as int means then how it allows comma. I like to insert all the student id's in a single record instead of insert no. of records. But 1st query is working fine, the issue is in 2nd only, if we select center value(except 1) in stud_id column means no result.