# I want to know if at least one value in one list is there in another list in sql

Tags: mysql

[image]

Hi

the column named Diagnosis is my first table (Table_A) and the column from Claim_NO is my second table (Table_B).

I want to return all the records from the second table (Table_B) where the the diagnosis is there in Table_A.

the script

```
Select * from Table_B b where b.diagnosis in(select * from Table_A)
```

will work, but in the diagnosis column there are some cases where there are two diagnosis separated by a coma.

How do I return the blue highlighted records

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.
Please take the [tour] to learn how Stack Overflow works and read [ask] on how to improve the quality of your question.
Then see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/271055/tips-for-asking-a-good-structured-query-language-sql-question/271056#271056 for SQL related questions.

Comment: What does `select version();` show?

Comment: please edit your question to show (as text, not an image) output of `show create table Table_B;` and `select version();`

Answer (score 0):

So with updated question, I see Table_A is your lookup table. Use FIND_IN_SET(,) to get the position of first argument in the second csv string argument

Hence the query would be like

```
SELECT * from Table_B b
JOIN Table_A a on FIND_IN_SET(a.Diagnosis,b.Diagnosis) > 0
```

This is inefficient as this query will scan Diagnosis column of Table_A in the comma separated value in Diagnosis column of Table_B and
get records of B where Diagnosis matches any of that in A

Highly encourage to read [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13465014) for more insight

Comment: thank you for ur response, but listItem from table A may have one or more items. So I want to return a value even if I match one value, please see my picture.

Comment: Hi, did the above solution work for you? @Lehlohonolo

Comment: Hi thank you very much. the solution worked very well, I created a new table by splitting the diagnosis and then joining on this new table as the solution suggested. thank you so much for all your help.

Comment: Ok great, in that case could you please mark accepted to the answer ? Up vote would be much appreciated. Thanks